# Motorola E4 pop up notifications disappear

Tags: notifications

How ca.n I view my Moto E4 pop up notifications,after I've viewed them or accidentally swiped them away,they literally disappeare and I CAN'T FIND them anywhere/ or how to.There has been many opportunities I've missed because I can't view the pop up notifications after the first view or accidentally swipe away,how can I get those notifications back to view,I've looked everywhere! Thanks for any help you can give in advance

Comment: There are many apps like this on Play Store which do this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ikvaesolutions.notificationhistorylog